# Assigning type to xyplot

Tags: r

Complete beginner at R here trying to perform nonmetric multidimensional scaling on a 95x95 matrix of similarities where 8 corresponds to very similar and 1 corresponds to very dissimilar. I also have an additional column (96th) signifying type and ranging from 0 to 1.

First I load the data:

```
dsimilarity <- read.table("d95x95matrix.txt",
                      header = T,
                      row.names = c("Y1", "Y2", "Y3", "Y4", "Y5", "Y6", "Y7", "Y8", "Y9", "Y10", "Y11", "Y12", "Y13", "Y14", "Y15", "Y16", "Y17", "Y18", "Y19", "Y20",
                                    "Y21", "Y22", "Y23", "Y24", "Y25", "Y26", "Y27", "Y28", "Y29", "Y30", "Y31", "Y32", "Y33", "Y34", "Y35", "Y36", "Y37", "Y38", "Y39", "Y40",
                                    "Y41", "Y42", "Y43", "Y44", "Y45", "Y46", "Y47", "Y48", "Y49", "Y50", "Y51", "Y52", "Y53", "Y54", "Y55", "Y56", "Y57", "Y58", "Y59", "Y60",
                                    "Y61", "Y62", "Y63", "Y64", "Y65", "Y66", "Y67", "Y68", "Y69", "Y70", "Y71", "Y72", "Y73", "Y74", "Y75", "Y76", "Y77", "Y78", "Y79", "Y80",
                                    "Y81", "Y82", "Y83", "Y84", "Y85", "Y86", "Y87", "Y88", "Y89", "Y90", "Y91", "Y92", "Y93", "Y94", "Y95"))
```

I convert the matrix of similarities into a matrix of dissimilarities, and exclude the 96th column:

```
ddissimilarity <- dsimilarity; ddissimilarity[1:95, 1:95] = 8 - ddissimilarity[1:95, 1:95]
```

Then I perform the nonmetric MDS using the Smacof function:

```
ordinal.mds.results <- smacofSym(ddissimilarity[1:95, 1:95], 
        type = c("ordinal"),
        ndim = 2,
        ties = "primary",
        verbose = T )
```

I create a new data frame (I'm following a guide and don't really know what's going on here):

```
mds.config <- as.data.frame(ordinal.mds.results$conf)
```

All well and good thus far (to my knowledge). However at this point I will try to create an xyplot of the data and get a good result using this code:

```
xyplot(D2 ~ D1, data = mds.config,
   aspect = 1,
   main = "Figure 1. MDS solution",
   panel = function (x, y) {
     panel.xyplot(x, y, col = "black")
     panel.text(x, y-.03, labels = rownames(mds.config),
                cex = .75)
   },
   xlab = "MDS Axis 1",
   ylab = "MDS Axis 2",
   xlim = c(-1.1, 1.1),
   ylim = c(-1.1, 1.1))
```

Now I want to create a figure that incorporates the type in column 96th and assigns different colors to observations of the two different types. However,  can't quite figure out how to do so. Does anyone have any ideas of where I'm going wrong here?

```
xyplot(D2 ~ D1, data = mds.config ~ ddissimilarity[96:96, 96:96],
   aspect = 1,
   main = "Figure 1. MDS solution",
   panel = function (x, y) {
     panel.xyplot(x, y, col = "black")
     panel.text(x, y-.03, labels = rownames(mds.config),
                cex = .75)
   },
   xlab = "MDS Axis 1",
   ylab = "MDS Axis 2",
   xlim = c(-1.1, 1.1),
   ylim = c(-1.1, 1.1),
   group = "Type")
```

Comment: Firstly, well done on a providing a great question, the only missing bit is some mock data to help us troubleshoot your issue. The package `smacof` has a plot functions. Have you tried using them? Is `xyplot` coming from the `lattice` package? If so option is `groups` with an *S*.

Comment: Is `xyplot` coming from the `lattice` package? If so the option is `groups` with an *S* and it should be a variable (you are passing a string). If the dataframe has a column called `Type` then the code should be `groups = Type`.